# Application.Printcommunication = True (results in error)

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro to auto-format a report in Excel 2010 that I send every week.  Part of the macro adjusts the Page Setup properties which includes changing the layout to Landscape and Legal size.

I can run it on my computer because my printer has Legal size paper as one of the defaults.  However, some people have to manually adjust their printer before printing on Legal Size paper and they are getting an error.

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'PrintCommunication' of object '_Application' failed

When I debug it highlights `Application.Printcommunication = True`.

When I change to `Application.PrintCommunication = False` the macro doesn't fully format it the way it's built (e.g., Zoom stays at 100%).

I thought a workaround might be to change their default printer to Nitro Pro (similar to Adobe Pro) prior to running the macro, but the error persists.

```vb
Sub Auto_Open()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.17)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.17)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.62)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.48)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.17)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.17)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 1200
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 60
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("N2:O2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("L1").Select
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 10.86
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 18.86
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 13.43
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 11.29
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 19.29
    Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33
    Range("I1").Select
    Range("G1").Select
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 13
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 18.71
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 19.86
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 13.57
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 11
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 11.43
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 12.71
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 15.86
    Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 41.86
    Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 18.57
    Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 28.86
    Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 42
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 12.71
    Range("K2:L2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Rows("1:1000").EntireRow.AutoFit
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "&""-,Bold""&12Weekly Staffing Summary Request &D"
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = "&D"
        .CenterFooter = "&P"
        .RightFooter = "&F"
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `.Papersize` to see if the code runs without it (I'm thinking that is the true issue, and it just manifests when you turn on the printer communication and the settings are shipped to the printer driver)? Also, does it work for them to set up their printer for Legal printing before they run the script?

Comment: I didn't try that thanks for the suggestion Karl, but I'm still getting the same error after commenting it out.  It doesn't run when the printer has to be setup for Legal printing.  And my workaround with trying to use Nitro PDF as the default printer didn't work either. I even tried making the default papersize in Nitro PDF to be Legal. Thanks for any other suggestions you might have!

Comment: I think I figured it out. I guess it wasn't the `.Papersize` afterall. I went line by line in the Page Setup and commented out each one until I figured out that it was the `.PrintQuality = 1200` causing the snag. It now runs regardless if the printer is setup for Legal size paper or not, and even works perfectly with Nitro Pro as the default printer! Thanks for giving me the second eye to point me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad the question helped.

Answer (score 5):

The line `.PrintQuality = 1200` pulled in from the recorded macro and was causing the error.  Removed that line and worked regardless of the printer and even worked with Nitro PDF as the default printer.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat late reply obviously, but today I had the same error. I problem was that my computer couldn't contact the default printer.

I changed it to only a PDF printer which is working internally in the computer, and then everything worked OK!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your printer settings (nothing to do with the macro) do not allow the macro to communicate with the printer. When setting printer settings, communication is required. Go into your printer settings and play around with the settings, I would imagine you simply need to "enable bidirectionally communication" and the problem will dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top & every thing will be fine:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "on error resume next" like this :

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.PrintCommunication = False
Err.Clear
```

and then :

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Err.Clear
```

It is not necessary to turn off PrintCommunication if you want only to make a page setup. But the difference can be seen in the execution time : the execution is faster with turning off the printer communication.

I have Excel 2010, and sometime PrintCommunication works fine, sometime not. I did not figure out why until now!

Answer (score 0):

I tried different approach for finding problem.

I didn't stop Print Communication and Run Macro
Application.PrintCommunication = True

On error, it displayed an Error Message.
in my case, it was Paper Size.
I corrected it to ".PaperSize = xlPaperLetter"

After That I gave multiple trial runs to Macro, It is working fine.

Finally, when everything was good. I stopped communication before page setup.
Application.PrintCommunication = False